# jqGrid: F2 key to activate inline editing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way or method in jqGrid to activate F2 key for inline-editing a row (just like Windows F2).
I mean, I want to keep the standard dblClick event and the pager "Edit" button (not replacing them). But furthermore, as mentioned, I would like the user can select a row and then hitting F2 key should act same way as EDIT button.

(my version is Free jqGrid 4.13.7-pre)

Thanks!

Comment: why someone downvote my question? please explain, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use free-jqGrid I do not know if the method bindKey is changed, but actually you can get idea how to do this.

Basically you will need to bind keydown event to the grid id and analyze if F2 is pressed and then using the parameter selrow to call the editing or what you want method.

```
$("#jqGrid").on("keydown", function(event){
    var target = $("#jqGrid").find('tr[tabindex=0]')[0];
    if(target) {
        if(event.keyCode === 113 && this.p.selrow) { // F2 key pressed and row is selected
            $(this).jqGrid("editRow", this.p.selrow, {keys:true} );
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Tony! I will try that. I supposed maybe there is a native option or something, but I think is not. I waited for Oleg's response but I think he's bussy now. I first tried to bind the "keydown" event to the selected row, but checked the jqgrid.src and found that when "restore" is fired (ESC key), the "keydown" event is unbinded. I mean, something like  $(tr).off("keydown") , so any row that was restored, lose that event and I should bind it again, which ends turning my code in a complicated mess, so I gave up

Comment: @Aberel Thanks - glad to help. I have tested this code with Guriddo jqGrid and it is working as expected.